# PouchDB getting huge on Android System using SQLite-Plugin

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, couchdb, pouchdb

In my current project i'm using PouchDB. As it's not published yet, i have only two users and around 60 documents.

The database on the android system is continously growing, currently reaching around 30 MB, far above the size of the CouchDB itself which is after compact around 60KB.

Compacting the database (local) makes not really a difference.  Is anyone seeing the same behaviour and can give me an explanation?

The docs itself are really small, just some text, so even writing one doc seems to cause an increase of at least 10 times its size.

The mentioned 30 MB represents the app size seen in Application Manager.

Comment: Couchdb keeps tracking of all versions of docs. Have you tried to compact server dB?

Comment: yes. in my reply to @nlawson (that i just wrote) i described how i'm testing it and what the results are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you storing attachments? PouchDB does not currently delete attachments during compaction, which is something [we're looking into](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/2818). Also, if you're not actually using the Web SQL adapter but rather IndexedDB, then Chrome and Chrome-like browsers such as Android on v37 or less will store attachments as base64 strings because binary is not supported.

Comment: no, there are just plain text docs. currently i have 155 documents, after compacting the database on the server it has less than 100KB. After that i delete all data on the android device, sync all and after that already 2MB of data are present.

Comment: Hm, without looking at your database, it's pretty difficult to tell what's going on. If you come to the #pouchdb Freenode IRC channel or send me the SQLite file in an email (https://github.com/nolanlawson), I can try to advise.

Comment: Ok, now i checked the db files and it's actually not them which have caused the increase of memory. There seems to be an issue (at least with my app) when it comes to queries and signing. i have a lot of files inside the app_webview/Cache folder. Probably for every request one, including the certificate (it seems). i query using https...